# Android Zoom IN animation for focus specific point

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation

I need to zoom in ImageView to show a part of image.
That's my animation XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fillAfter="true">

  <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:duration="2000"
       android:fromXScale="1"
       android:fromYScale="1"
       android:toXScale="2"
       android:toYScale="2"
       android:pivotX="100%"
       android:pivotY="0%" >
  </scale>
</set>
```

It works fine and "zoom in" the image to the to-right corner, but the image is scaled also and it finish over others item like button, others images.
I'm looking for a way to "block" image inside is box (ImageView init size) and hide the part of image I got when scale image.
I show you my problem and I hope there is a solution.

Pre-animation (original):
[image: pre-animation]
Post-animation (button over image):
[image: post-animation]

What I need:
[image: what i want]

Comment: try this library it's simple  https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView

Comment: Thanks !!!! It works with this lib....

Comment: Is there a way to set the max scale zoom ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
   PhotoViewAttacher imageAttacher;
   imageAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
   imageAttacher.update();
```

Find Gradle dependency here:

http://theandroidlibrary.com/Control/Photo-View